# Safely hiding PDF-invoices on a website using PHP

Tags: php, email, attachment, email-attachments

I'm making a website, where people can sign up for a beach volleyball holiday. The website doesn't have online payment, so how it works is, that people register themself (on a good ol' html form), whereafter you'll recieve an email, that should contain the invoice. I've made it, so this invoice is generated using FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/ - even though I assume it's not important for the answer to this question). So FPDF takes a bunch of PHP-variables and makes a PDF-file with it and puts this file in a directory on the FTP-server.

Now, I can see two ways of getting this invoice from the server to the person who just signed up (because they'll want it straight away for confirmation of their signup):

1) Attaching it in an email (which I have tried for about an hour and could get it to do). If this is the better option - then how do I do it? Last time I tried, I drowned in a bunch of information about MIME, which I had never heard of before. Was that the right track, or is there an easier way of doing it? I also read something about Zend_framework and PHPMailer, but don't really know what approach is the correct (or better) one...

or...

2) Put a link in the email to the invoice. Now, if I do this, then the URL should somehow be masked or encrypted, since it would make it too easy to find the other invoices, if the link they're visiting is:

```
http://www.something.com/invoicefolder/invoice16.pdf
```

Obviously, people could just change that 16, to 15, and all of a sudden, those who has a snitch of web-knowledge would have access to all the invoices.

Which is why I humbly ask you, StackOverflow... What would be the best (or the safest way) to get this invoice from the FTP-server to a client, where the communication-method is e-mail?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I drowned in a bunch of information about MIME, which I had never heard of before

Sorry, but this really sets my alarm bells ringing - you must have a basic understanding of the technologies involed to implement solutions in code.

Yes, you can attach it to an email - however I'd recommend staying clear of the zend framework until you've got a lot more familiar with software development. [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) both provide a simple, well-documented API which handles attachments on emails.

A simple solution to the problem would be to keep the PDF files outside the document root and use a proxy script which performas additional validation. e.g.

```
define('MY_SECRET', 'some rAnd0m strlng');
define('DOC_DIR','/path/to/files');

function getIdHash($id)
{
   return sha1($id . MY_SECRET);
}

$id=(integer) $_GET['doc_id'];
$filename=DOC_DIR . '/' . $id . '.pdf';
if ( ($_GET['chk']==getIdHash($id)) 
    && file_exists($filename) && is_readable($filename)) {
   header("Content-type:application/pdf");
   readfile($filename);
   exit;
} else {
   header("Status: 404 Not Found");
   print "Document does not exist or not authorized";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look into PHPMailer and just send the invoice as an attachment. PHPMailer is quite easy to use and has some great example code.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the invoices are not in a public folder (i.e. under the doc root) and let PHP serve them on request. This way you can force people to login.

Another want would be to only attach the invoice to the email although people tend to lose emails and they still want to have access to their invoices.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a controller file say "invoice.php" which will forcefully download the specified pdf file, your url should look like this

lets suppose you have stored a file 54219683.pdf in invoices folder, you can send following url in emails

http://www.example.com/invoice.php?id=54219683

Here is a very simple example

```
//file: invoice.php
//content type
$file = $_GET['id'].'.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
//open/save dialog box
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$file"');
//read from server and write to buffer
readfile($file);
```

you can find more detail to download a pdf through php file on http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download

you should not save your actual files with exact mapping to database id but you should use a random unique number for each invoice file name which can't be guessed by hackers.

Problem comes when you save your files with a serial number so don't save your pdf files like 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf but save with a random number, secondly don't send emails with exact url of the files but download through a controller file in which you can add more restrictions and you can also keep track of each download.

Answer (score 0):

I would employ a scheme similar to share lockers like RapidShare:

```
domain.com/invoice/{md5($email)}/{time()}.pdf
```

This solution is obscure enough to be safe. It would be pretty difficult for someone to guess (or bruteforce) the MD5 digest of e-mail address and the time at which the invoice was generated.

Additionally, you could send the e-mail with the attachment, like others have said, it's pretty straightforward if you use a library like SwiftMailer. Even [implementing your own](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/9bbd9455e48379efa8283f6a03369c0759407476/phunction/Net.php#L209) it's not that difficult.